# How can I show the menu bar in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, app-menu

How can I show the menu bar for all applications in Windows 11, at the top of the screen?

I haven't used Windows since NT, and have to for some work I'm doing, and don't seem to see an easy way to enable this feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all apps have a menu. And for apps that have a standard menu the shortcut has always been <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>. With <kbd>Alt</kbd> the accelerator key is also shown so you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd>[+...] to quickly open the menus or menu entries. This hasn't been changed for decades

For some app that don't have a standard menu then obviously it depends on the mercy of that app to provide a way to access its menu. For MS' ribbon interface the shortcut is still the same, which is <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd>[+...]

Answer (score 0):

**(1) The Menu Bar** (= Task Bar) for any and all apps that you want is a bar across the bottom of the screen.

Natively you cannot relocate this bar.

The bar is also called a Launcher (a la Apple) and icons can go left side of the bar or center of the bar.

That is all you can do  natively in Windows 11.

Windows 11 is fairly tightly nailed down.

I am not sure about 3rd party offerings but these can get bashed in feature updates.

It is called Explorer Patcher and has been known to cause issues, so beware.

See [Move Task Bar](https://beebom.com/how-move-windows-11-taskbar-top-sides/#:%7E:text=To%20further%20customize%20it%2C%20right,at%20the%20bottom%2Dleft%20corner.)

**(2) App by App:** Otherwise App Menus are App by App.

**(3) Office Toolbar:** There was an old Office Toolbar that could be added to and moved around. But that is very long gone (not in Office 2003 or later).

**Summary:**  Anything of a menu nature in Windows NT4 (which I have here) is gone.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - my question is not about the taskbar, but how to show where "menus" used to be back in NT - File/Edit/etc ? Thanks!

Comment: App Menus now are App by App.  Given this, I did assume you meant Task Bar. I do have a Windows NT VM and it sets up default more or less like modern systems.

Comment: You may be thinking of the Office Toolbar (Office 2002 and not later, possibly before) which had some flexibility, but that is long gone.